# How to Record Sound From a USB mic with Java

Tags: java, audio, usb, recording

Right now, I can get sound from a normal line - in mic through the mic port. However, I do not know how I'd access a piece of hardware directly thorough Java to get sound. Could anyone help with this?

Basically, I need it to record for some amount of time, then record the input sound into a .mp3 or whatever file.

Comment: I think gtgaxiola's idea is correct. You don't need to access the hardware, but it's driver.

Comment: JavaSound Reosurces gives lots of examples of this kind of thing: http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#capture_source

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [Java Sound API](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CapturingAudiowithJavaSoundAPI.htm)